# Undefined result from node-mssql query

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, promise

Well, I'm new to NodeJS. Although I have some basics knowledge, now I'm a little bit stuck with tihs code below. The goal would be to create a common module which can execute the given SQL query and return its result.

The problem is pretty clear. My method returns earlier than the result could come back from the SQL server. I tried to solve it in dozen ways, but none of them worked. I really appreciate if somebody could explain what I did wrong and what's the proper way to make this code works.

database \ config.js

```
module.exports = {
    user: 'mssql',
    password: 'mssql',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'mssql',
    stream: true
};
```

database \ database.js

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = require('./config');

module.exports = function(query) {

    var result = [];

    sql.connect(config).then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(query);

        request.on('row', function (row) {
            result.push(row);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return result;
    });
}
```

routes \ index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var queries = require('../database/queries.json');
var database = require('../database/database');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        books: database(queries.books)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You should use promises inside your router.get()'s function,First fetch the result from DB , .then() send response(res.render())

Comment: I already tried it, here is the code I used: router.get('/', function (req, res, next) { var books; database(queries.books).then(function (result) { books = result; }); res.render('index', { books: books }); });
For some reason the "books = result" line is not called and the page is not rendered.

Comment: The reason is simple 'your database query is an I/O activity and would execute in async manner',Your code should be like this : router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 var books; 
 database(queries.books)
  .then(function (result) { 
    books = result; 
    res.render('index', { books: books });
  }); 
   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `database` function should return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object which will contain the result of the query when resolved. For this, you do not need the `result` array:

database \ database.js

```
module.exports = function(query) {

    return sql.connect(config).then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // Return the Promise object that will contain the result of 
        // the query when resolved
        return request.query(query);
    });
};
```

routes \ index.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // The object returned after calling 'database' is the 'Promise'
  // object that contains the result of the query.
  database(queries.books).then(function(result) {
    res.render('index', {
        books: result
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I already tried something similar. Nevertheless, I did another try with your code. For some reason it's still not working. The database(queries.books) method is called, but than nothing happens. No exception in the log and the database connection is alive. Moreover, if I immediately list the result in the database.js file I can see the books - request.query(query).then(function (recordset) { console.dir(recordset); }).

Comment: I've edited the answer. The `database` function was supposed to return the promise but I forgot the `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now great. Let me have a final question. For rendering the page I have to use two SQL queries. What is the best way to do that? I tried to concatenate the promises and execute one-by-one, but the second SQL call is stuck. So I tried something like this: database(queries.books).then(...).then(database(queries.albums).then(...).then(function () { res.render(...). Do I have to create new database module for each queries?

Comment: Sorry for the duplication. As it turned out, the connection is closed as soon as the first query is executed. That's why I have no result for the second one. It's always difficult to be a newbie. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'd take difficulty over boredom any day.